# Conflicting lstinputlisting and table reference number

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing, listings

I'm using this `\lstinputlisting[float=h,frame=tb,caption= {Normal model},label= {lst:Norm}, language = {R}]{Model.glm1.txt}`
 and I've got a labelled table in the same chapter of my essay, but referencing both result in a conflicting reference number. How do I solve this problem?

For the `lstlisting` It was labelled *Listing 4.1* and the table have got label *Table 4.1*. Referencing both each gives **4.1**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a full minimal working example (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: What is the conflict here? Both having the same reference number?

Comment: Exactly, both are having the same reference number. Though, clicking on each one of them direct me to the right table but I the reference number in both cases to be different.

Comment: @Usman I don't understand the problem. If you have `see listing~\ref{lst:foo} and table~\ref{tab:bla}` then from the context it is clear if you mean the listing or the table, regardless if they have the same number or not. (You probably also have a section 4.1, haven't you? Is it a problem, too?)

Comment: @clemens, I got confused because the `listing` is also in a table format. But I get it now, I'll address each one accordingly, listing or table. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP misunderstood numbering scheme of listings and tables.

Answer (score 1):

Such ambiguities with respect to the referred entity can be solved by either manual specification of the related entity as Clemens suggested or use `cleveref`, for example, that has a built-in 'database' of counters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

See \cref{tab:nice} and \cref{lst:Norm} 

\begin{table}
  \caption{dummy table}\label{tab:nice}
\end{table}

\lstinputlisting[float=h,frame=tb,caption= {Normal model},label= {lst:Norm}, language = {C}]{helloworldexample.c}
\end{document}
```

helloworldexample.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
```

[image]